# Check for specific item in an array before checking others in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an `array` of `object` of which I want to check if the any of the `object` has a title 'food' before checking for others but at the moment, it checks sequentially. Bellow is my code

```js
let db = {
  users: [{
      id: 1,
      title: "food"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "stone"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "food"
    }
  ]
}

for (let index in db.users) {
  if (db.users[index].title === "food") {
    console.log("Its food");
    continue;
  }
  console.log("Its not food");
}
```

With the code above, I get the following result

```
Its food
Its not food
Its food
```

How do i do it such that i it checks for all food before any other title so i get the result

```
Its food
Its food
Its not food
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use if and else?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what your are trying to achieve. But you may filter your array first maybe ? Like this : db.users.filter(user => user.title === 'food')

Comment: At any point of time there will be either of the two - `food` or `no food`. So if you want it in order, better use loops separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the `"food"` items to the beginning of the array and then loop through it

```js
let db = { users: [ { id: 1, title: "food" },  { id: 2, title: "stone" },  { id: 3, title: "food" }] };

db.users.sort((a, b) => (b.title === "food") - (a.title === "food"))
        .forEach(a => console.log(a.title === "food" ? "It's food" : "It's not food"))
```

Subtracting booleans returns 1, -1 or 0

```
true - false === 1
false - true === -1
true - true === 0
```

So, if `a.title === food` and `b.title` isn't, `-1` will be returned from the [`compareFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description). So, `a` will be placed ahead of `b` in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain an `array` and use [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) (adds at last) if **Its not food** and use [Array.unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) (adds at the beginning) to add the value at beginning if **Its food**.

```js
let db = {users: [{id: 1,title: "food"},{id: 2,title: "stone"}, {id: 3,title: "food"}]};

let result = [];
for(let index in db.users) {
    if(db.users[index].title === "food") {
        result.unshift("Its food");
        continue;
    }
    result.push("Its not food");
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @WhiteHox - Then you will need to sort the array first!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print first all `foods` and then items which are not food , then you can use two different loop and print seperately

first for loop for all foods

```
for(let index in db.users) {
    if(db.users[index].title === "food") {
        console.log("Its food");
    }
}
```

second for loop for all items which are not a food.

```
for(let index in db.users) {
    if(db.users[index].title != "food") {
        console.log("Its not food");
    }
}
```

---

To reduce iterations we can use filter and save filtered items separately and then iterate though each array

```
let foodItems = db.users.filter(user => user.title === 'food')
let nonFoodItems = db.users.filter(user => user.title != 'food')
```

now iterate through each array which are filtered based on title

Answer (score 1):

You could map the strings, sort and reverse the array for getting the right text in wanted order.

```js
let db = { users: [ { id: 1, title: "food" },  { id: 2, title: "stone" },  { id: 3, title: "food" }] }, 
    msg = db.users
        .map(({ title }) => title === 'food' ? "It's food" : "It isn't food")
        .sort()
        .reverse();

msg.forEach(m => console.log(m));
```

You could take a generator and get the values in the wanted order.

```js
function* getInOrder([{ title }, ...rest]) {
    if (title === "food") {
        yield "It's food";
        if (rest.length) yield* getInOrder(rest);
    } else {
        if (rest.length) yield* getInOrder(rest);
        yield "It isn't food";
    }
}
let db = { users: [ { id: 1, title: "food" },  { id: 2, title: "stone" },  { id: 3, title: "food" }] };

[...getInOrder(db.users)].forEach(m => console.log(m));
```

Comment: Thanks but i wasn't trying to get the result in wanted order but execute in wanted order

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.sort()` method to sort them and map over them

```js
let db = {
    users: [
        {
           id: 1,
            title: "food"
        }, 
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "stone"
        }, 
        {
            id: 3,
            title: "food"
        }
    ]
}

const sortTitle = (a,b) => (a.title === "food" && b.title !== "food") ? -1 : 1;
const mapOutput = it => { if(it.title === "food") { console.log("Its food"); } else { console.log("Its not food");}};

db.users
.sort(sortTitle)
.map(mapOutput);
```